# Bash - test existence and value of argument in one if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, lazy-evaluation

I'm writing a script that needs two input files. I wrote the following code:

```
if (( $# < 3 || ! ( -f $1 && -f $2 ) )); then
    echo Cannot open input files
    exit 1
fi
```

But if I supply only one input file, I get this error:

```
line 4: ((: 1 < 3 || ! ( -f tests/example && -f  ) : missing `)' (error token is "tests/example && -f  ) ")
```

I guess the OR evaluation isn't "lazy", so the `-f $1` works because it's replaced by `-f tests/example`, but `-f $2` causes an error.

Is there some way to "force lazy evaluation" (if `$# < 3` don't try to evaluate the rest) in the `if` statement? Or should I be doing things differently?

Comment: You can use `eval` for lazy evaluation in bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm writing a script that needs two input files.

Why are you checking if the number of arguments is less than `3` in order to exit?  You need to ensure that there are no fewer than `2` arguments.  Use *short-circuting* for all the checks.  Say:

```
if [[ $# < 2 || ! -f "$1" || ! -f "$2" ]]; then
    echo Cannot open input files
    exit 1
fi
```

---

Actually, even the following would suffice for your question:

```
if [[ ! -f "$1" || ! -f "$2" ]]; then
    echo Cannot open input files
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`(( ... ))` is for maths operations in shell.

Rewrite your if condition like this:

```
[[ $# < 3 || ! ( -f "$1" && -f "$2" ) ]]
```